# How to move Apply coupon code button on product page

Tags: magento2.2, coupon-codes

Is it possible to move apply coupon code button on product page and it will work or not ?

Comment: I also want to show all available coupon codes of  current products in product page

Comment: So if you want to apply coupon code functionality in the product page, how would you apply the coupon code when the cart is empty?

Comment: I will set the validation Kindly add product first. OR is there any other solution to pass selected coupon to cart page that is also ok for me.

Answer (score 2):

Create `catalog_product_view.xml`at `app/design/frontend/{VendorTheme}/{ThemeName}/Magento_Catalog/layout`

**and below code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
  <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Coupon" name="checkout.cart.coupon" as="coupon" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/coupon.phtml"/>
    </body>
</referenceContainer>
</page>
```

Comment: Placed but functionality is not working

Comment: what is not working?